# Waterline/SailsJs prevent nested (relationship) save of model

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sails.js, waterline

I have a model "User" that has a Many-to-One relationship with a "Subject".

**User.js**

```
attributes: {
    subject: { model: 'subject' },
}
```

**Subject.js**

```
attributes: {
    name: { type: 'string', unique: true, required: true },
}
```

When I call the blueprint create function for a User "/user" and pass in the data:

```
{
    "name":"Test",
    "subject":{"name":"Do Not Allow"}
}
```

It creates the user and also creates the Subject. However I do not want to allow the subject to be created, I only want to be able to attach an existing one. For example I would like it to reject the subject being created using the above data but allow the subject to be attached by using the below data.

```
{
    "name":"Test",
    "subject":1
}
```

I tried adding a policy (shown below) but this only stops the subject from being created using the URL "/subject" and not the nested create shown above.

```
'SubjectController':{
    'create':false
}
```

**Edit**
To help understand what is going on here this is the lifecycle process it is going through:

```
Before Validation of Subject
After Validation of Subject
Before Creating Subject
After Creating Subject
Before Validation of User
After Validation of User
Before Creating User
Before Validation of User
After Validation of User
After Creating User
```

As you can see it is validating and creating the subject before it even gets to validating or creating the user.

Comment: Could you add the model?

Comment: I have added the models.

Comment: What request do you make to create a user with a named subject?

Comment: A request to "/user"

Comment: A GET or POST request? What params are you using?

Comment: POST. All of this information is in the question if you read it. The data being sent is: {"name":"Test","subject":{"name":"Do Not Allow"}}

Comment: Well, the subject is not created in my case.

Comment: Are you using the blueprint route?

Comment: Interesting issue... I think only way to handle this is to make custom method for it (override blueprint create method for message). Sails guys should check this behavior cause it should not firstly create relations imho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to avoid the creation of an associated object when calling the blueprint creation route.

Create a policy (I've named it `checkSubjectAndHydrate`) and add it into the `policies.js` file:

```
// checkSubjectAndHydrate.js
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {

  // We can create a user without a subject
  if (_.isUndefined(req.body.subject)) {
    return next();
  }

  // Check that the subject exists
  Subject
    .findOne(req.body.subject)
    .exec(function (err, subject) {
      if (err) return next(err);

      // The subject does not exist, send an error message
      if (!subject) return res.forbidden('You are not allowed to do that');

      // The subject does exist, replace the body param with its id
      req.body.subject = subject.id;

      return next();
  });

};

// policies.js
module.exports.policies = {

  UserController: {
    create: 'checkSubjectAndHydrate',
    update: 'checkSubjectAndHydrate',
  }

};
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I should say that Sails do recommend that you do not use the blueprint routes in production so this should never be needed but its good to know that is is possible. Also in your answer you set the policy for create and update to be "checkSubject" but I think it should be "checkSubjectAndHydrate"?

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom type for subject, and add your logic inside model. I'm not 100% sure I understood the attach sometimes part but maybe this could help:

models/User.js

```
module.exports = {

    schema: true,

    attributes: {
        name: {
            type: 'string'
        },

        subject: {
            type: 'json',
            myValidation: true
        }
    },

    types: {
        myValidation: function(value) {
            // add here any kind of logic...

            // for example... reject if someone passed name key
            return !value.name;
        }
    }
};
```

You can find more info here http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/validations at the bottom of the page.

If I totally missed the point... The second option would be to add beforeCreate and beforeUpdate lifecycle callback to your model like this:

models/User.js

```
 module.exports = {

    schema: true,

    attributes: {
        name: {
            type: 'string'
        },

        subject: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    },

    beforeCreate: function (values, cb) {

        // for example... reject creating of subject if anything else then value of 1
        if (values.subject && values.subject !== 1) return cb('make error obj...');

        cb();
    },


    beforeUpdate: function (values, cb) {
        // here you can add any kind of logic to check existing user or current update values that are going to be updated
        // and allow it or not

        return cb();
    }
};
```

By using this you can use one logic for creating and another one for updating... etc...

You can find more info here: http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/lifecycle-callbacks

**EDIT**

Realized you have trouble with relation, and in above examples I thought you are handling type json...

```
module.exports = {

    schema: true,

    attributes: {
        name: {
            type: 'string'
        },

        subject: {
            model: 'subject'
        }
    },

    beforeValidate: function (values, cb) {

        // subject is not sent at all, so we just go to next lifecycle
        if (!values.subject) return cb();

        // before we update or create... we will check if subject by id exists...
        Subject.findOne(values.subject).exec(function (err, subject) {
            // subject is not existing, return an error
            if (err || !subject) return cb(err || 'no subject');

            //

            // you can also remove subject key instead of sending error like this:
            // delete values.subject;

            //

            // subject is existing... continue with update
            cb();
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but im not sure any of the above are going to solve my issue. When logging out the value (or values) of the above validations/before functions they both return an ID for subject. This means that the subject has already been created before these checks have been made.

Comment: Nope, its not created... Values contain values that ARE going to be created. So you have opportunity to check them, convert them or whatever before they hit database.

Comment: I think this is true for the main object being created (In my example this would be the user) but not the relationship model(s), in my case the subject. If I add a beforeCreate into the user and log out values.subject it returns an ID. Therefore the creation of that object has already been made.

Comment: You can do a query using that ID and gather all info you need. Then when query is done you just call cb() to finish cycle. I didn't realise subject is relation... from your question it look like its JSON type. Ill update my answer

Comment: You didnt realise subject is a relation? The first line in my question is: "I have a model 'User' that has a Many-to-One relationship with a 'Subject'."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116194/discussion-between-hlozancic-and-glen-robson).

Answer (score 0):

You should be passing the subject id (e.g. `1`) instead of an object (e.g. `{ name: 'Hello, World!' }`) containing the name of the subject as it's not necessarily unique.

If it is unique, you should replace the object by its id inside a `beforeValidate` for example.

```
// User.js

module.exports = {

  ...

  beforeValidate: function (users, callback) {
    // users = [{
    //   "name":"Test",
    //   "subject":{"name":"Do Not Allow"}
    // }]

    async.each(users, function replaceSubject(user, next) {
      var where = {};
      if (_.isObject(user.subject) && _.isString(user.subject.name)) {
        where.name = user.subject.name;
      } else if(_.isInteger(user.subject)) {
        where.id = user.subject;
      } else {
        return next();
      }

      // Check the existence of the subject
      Subject
        .findOne(where)
        .exec(function (err, subject) {
          if (err) return next(err);

          // Create a user without a subject if it does not exist
          user.subject = subject? subject.id : null;
          next();
      });
    }, callback);

    // users = [{
    //   "name":"Test",
    //   "subject":1
    // }]
  }

};
```

Comment: I understand that I can pass in an ID but what im trying to do is prevent a subject being created from the create user method. If someone wants to hack my application and add lots of subjects they will be able to do it by passing the subject as shown in my first example.

Comment: Are you adding the before Validate to the Subject or the User model?

Comment: Inside the user model

Comment: Yes this would not work as at the point of beforeValidate on the user model the new Subject would have already been created. Therefore Subject.find would return the new Subject that I do not want to be saved.

Comment: Oh, I see now that you've added the lifecycle! I'm gonna make another answer then